# Is there a way of detecting if the browser will freeze the DOM while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, parallax, browser-feature-detection

Is there a way of detecting if the browser will freeze the DOM or disable JavaScript while scrolling? It's known that some mobile browsers do this, and it effectively kills scrolling-based effects like parallax and animations. I'd like to effectively implement the following pseudocode without resorting to UA sniffing:

```
if (!browserWillFreezeWhileScrolling) {
    initializeScrollingEffects();
} else {
    initializeFallbackScript(); // maybe unnecessary
}
```

From what I can see, Modernizr doesn't check it.