# detect if browser will fire javascript while scrolling

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-feature-detection

Some mobile browsers freeze javascript while scrolling, and therefore I won't receive scroll events until the user stops scrolling. Is there a way to detect this 'feature' so as to allow for it in a smart way? Or is the only solution to check the user agent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17205074/139010

Comment: I guess the traditional scroll detecting never gonna work properly on touch devices, try to use touch/gesture detection instead.

Comment: I understand that but how can I check when to use touch/gesture detection instead?